# How to pass Encodable or Decodable as parameter in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, api

I am learning JSONParsing. I followed tutorials and what I got is this:

```
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/test-api/public/api/register") else { return }

    var request  = URLRequest(url: url)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let newUser = User.init(name: self.collectionTF[0].text, email: self.collectionTF[1].text, password: self.collectionTF[2].text)

    do {

        let jsonBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(newUser)

        request.httpBody = jsonBody

    } catch { }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {

            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any]

            print(json!)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if json!["status"] as! Int == 200
            {
                GeneralHelper.shared.keepLoggedIn()

                NavigationHelper.shared.moveToHome(fromVC: self)
            }

            }

        } catch { print(error.localizedDescription)}

        }.resume()
```

Ok, this is what I have done for register. Now, I want to create a Helper, which will do the same thing with `@escaping` as I we all need the parsed `JSON` in return.

So, I am passing the `endPoint` as String and then trying to pass this newUser which is a `Encodable`, it can be a `Decodable` as well in future, but it throws an error `Cannot invoke 'encode' with an argument list of type '(Codable)'`. Can anyone please help? And, is it better this way, by calling this function multiple times when it comes to `JSONParsing`?

Edit: - So, I am now using the `networkRequestfunction` and here is what I have done.

```
 let newData = User.init(name: "Rob", email: "abc@gmail.com", password: "12345678")

ApiHelper.sharedInstance.networkRequest_Post(urlString: "register", header: nil, encodingData: newData) { (response: User, urlRes, error) in
        <#code#> }
```

Now, it gives me this error: `Cannot convert value of type '(User, _, _) -> ()' to expected argument type '(_?, HTTPURLResponse?, Error?) -> ()'`. Any help?

Comment: I have created wrapper classes You should try https://github.com/PrashantKT/AlamofireHelperLayer

Answer (score 3):

I have used the same functionality in my project

Hope the below code will help

```
    func networkRequest_Post<T: Decodable, Q: Encodable>(urlString: String,header:[String:String]?,encodingData: Q,completion: @escaping (T?, HTTPURLResponse?, Error?) -> ()) {

    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 300.0
    config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 300.0
    if header != nil{
        config.httpAdditionalHeaders = header
    }
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    do {
        let jsonBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(encodingData)
        request.httpBody = jsonBody
    } catch {}
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data,response, err) in

        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }
        if let err = err {
            print("Failed to fetch data:", err.localizedDescription, "Error Description\(err)")
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            print(String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as Any)
            let dataReceived = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                completion(dataReceived,response as? HTTPURLResponse,err)
        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Failed to serialize json:", jsonErr, jsonErr.localizedDescription)
            completion( nil,response as? HTTPURLResponse,jsonErr)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Use -

```
         let newdata = User(name: "Abhi", email: "jhjhj@jhj.co", password: "123hguhj")
    networkRequest_Post(urlString: "YOUR_URL", header: nil, encodingData: newdata) { (RESPONSE_DATA:User?, URL_RESPONSE, ERROR) in
        // Do your network work here
    }

    struct User : Codable {
      var name: String?
      var email: String?
      var password: String?
    }
```

Comment: Ok, can you show me a function like calling the function with a decodable and an encodable, sorry but things are not so much clear to me, when it comes to generics, I am very new to it. A little guide will help me.

Comment: Do I need the Header?

Comment: I had a requirement for header so added it. I have made it option and updated my code

Comment: I have updated my question, please check the Edit part this is giving me a headache now. Do you know what is wrong here?

Comment: The expected type is optional and you are passing non optional value, Please pass the value as below ApiHelper.sharedInstance.networkRequest_Post(urlString: "register", header: nil, encodingData: newData) { (response: User?, urlRes?, error?) in

Comment: I have updated my answer and tested in xcode, Kindly check my ans

Comment: My `struct User` was of type `Encodable`. should I change it to `Codable`. That's why it was not working.

Comment: Yes, please make it codable and let me know if that worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182600/discussion-between-rob13-and-abhinav-jha).

Answer (score 1):

You can user **Generics** in following way...

```
func requestWith<T>(method: HTTPMethod, action: String,  params: Parameters?, for type: T.Type, success: @escaping (AnyObject) -> Void, failure: @escaping (AnyObject) -> Void) where T: Codable {


//do your stuff..your logic goes here..see below example

     guard let serverData = response.data else {
           return
        }

   do {
     let decoder = JSONDecoder()
     let responseData = try decoder.decode(type, from: serverData)
       success(responseData as AnyObject)
    } catch {
      print("Error = \(error.localizedDescription)")
       failure(error.localizedDescription as AnyObject)
   }

}
```

Comment: Codable is super of Decodable & Encodable protocol...just try it.

Comment: Unspecified `AnyObject` is inappropriate for a generic function. Better `func requestWith<T>(method: HTTPMethod, action: String,  params: Parameters?, success: @escaping (T) -> Void, failure: @escaping (Error) -> Void) where T: Codable {
`

Comment: I know, here you have used `JSONDecoder`, so I am asking what should I do if I want to `encode`?

Comment: @vadian, it is just an example:)

Comment: Yes, but please suggest better examples for the people who copy and paste code together.

Comment: @vadian Can you show me an example or anything where both JSONEncoder and Decoder are used? Or any tutorial that I can follow?

Comment: Great example! I think this just got me hooked to generics... 